# jquery add class to this clicked element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I generate several rows `<tr>` with tasks. Now, each task can be marked as complete by clicking on a `span`. I do that with an ajax request.

Here's the html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>#1</td>
        <td><span class="icon-complete-a to-heal"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>#2</td>
        <td><span class="icon-complete-a to-heal"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>#3</td>
        <td><span class="icon-complete-a to-heam"></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now when I click on a certain span element, only that element should change class.

I use this to change class:

```
$(".to-heal").addClass("completed-task");
```

But all my span elements are getting the completed class.

So I tried with the following:

```
$(this).find(".to-heal").addClass("completed-task");
```

But that doesn't work.

Any help?

**UPDATE**

I tried using the `$(this).addClass("completed-task");`

Here is the full ajax request I'm using:

```
$(".to-heal").click(function() {

    var task = $(this).attr("data-task");

    $.ajax({

        type: "post",
        url: "assets/js/ajax/mark-as-complete.php",
        data: { 'task': task },
        success: function() {

            $(this).addClass("completed-task");

            $(".completed-task").click(function() {

                var task = $(this).attr("data-task");

                $.ajax({

                    type: "post",
                    url: "assets/js/ajax/mark-as-incomplete.php",
                    data: { 'task': task },
                    success: function() {

                        $(this).removeClass("completed-task");

                    }

                });

            });

        }

    });

});
```

The markup classes are not the same anymore, as I used dummy classes for quick explanation. Sorry for that...

Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context of element is lost in ajax call. you can use `context` option in ajax to set any elements context:

```
context:this,
```

Ajax call snippet:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "post",
   context:this,
   url: "assets/js/ajax/mark-as-incomplete.php",
   data: { 'task': task },
   success: function() {
       $(this).removeClass("completed-task");
   }
});
```

Comment: I tried that in my ajax succes function, but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @JeroenBellemans: check the updated answer. the element context is lost in ajax call.

Comment: Another way would be the way ES6 handles the ()=>{} syntax, simply putting `var _this = this;` before `$.ajax`, then using `$(_this).removeClass(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

try using following code, This is a prefered way jQuery

**JS**

```
$(".mark-as-complete").on("click", function(){
    $(this).addClass("completed);
});
```

`$(".mark-as-complete").on("click", function(){` will trigger click function on span click

within that click function we are checking `$(this)` which will add class to clicked span.

Answer (score 1):

You say you GENERATE the rows.

If you generate them on the client you need to delegate. Take the nearest static element to the generated rows, for example the table:

```
<table id="markTable">
```

then delegate like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#markTable").on("click",".to-heal",function() {
    $(this).addClass("completed-task");
  });
  $("#markTable").on("click",".completed-task",function() {
    $(this).removeClass("completed-task");
  });
});
```

or just

```
$(function() {
  $("#markTable").on("click",".to-heal",function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("completed-task");
  });
});
```

UPDATE:

```
$(function() {
  $(".to-heal").on("click",function() {
    var task = $(this).attr("data-task");
    var completed = $(this).hasClass("completed-task");
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      context:this,
      url: "assets/js/ajax/mark-as-"+(completed?"in":"")+"complete.php",
      data: { 'task': task },
      success: function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("completed-task",!$(this).hasClass("completed-task"));
      }
    });
  });
});
```

or have ONE php that takes the parameter complete or incomplete

Comment: Oops!, I missed that static ancestor and dynamic child selector logic.. good catch @mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `this`

```
$('span').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("completed");
});
```

When you use an selector it search for the selected class or id and it will apply the property to all the existed selectors.