# jquery for check / uncheck checkbox and pass argument

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a tasklist which have check boxes for completed/not completed tasks. I am working towards having it so when a task is checked, it uses ajax to update the table to say its been completed. And vice versa and untick would send a command to change it from completed to not completed again.

The method was working towards using, but realize I can't quite achieve what I want was this:

$taskid = unique id for each of the tasks.

```
'<input  type="checkbox" onclick="checkboxChecked('.$taskid.')" value="1" >'
```

When this is clicked it calls the following function(and passes the taskid to it)

```
function checkboxChecked(id)
{
var x = "task"+id;

$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "form_taskchecked.post.php",
  data: { action: "checked", 
          id: id }
})

.done(function( msg ) {
    //success
     $('#'+x).toggleClass("task-done");        


})
.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});


}
```

on my server side the php looks like this

```
if ($_POST['action'] == "checked") {
//SEND SQL TO LIST TASK AS COMPLETED

}
else if ($_POST['action'] == "unchecked") {
//SEND SQL TO LIST TASK AS NOT COMPLETED
}
```

it was when i got to this point I realized that I would need a second function for the ajax call that would instead send the same details but action as "unchecked". But how do i go about doing that, if I use an event handler instead like this, I don't understand how I can (a) reference a specific checkbox(do I listen for a class instead and have all checkboxes have that class?) and (b) how do I pass the value of the taskid to it, which I need for the php part.

```
$('#myCheckBox').click (function ()
{
var thisCheck = $(this);
if (thischeck.is (':checked'))
{
   // ajax call for checked box
}


});
```

To summarize, how can i differentiate between a check and uncheck and send an ajax call accordingly, with an ID value passed to it.

Comment: Is this not identical to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304829/jquery-add-class-to-this-clicked-element/30305050#30305050 - add a class to the checkbox and give each checkbox the id of taskid

Comment: it's be much easier yet tidier to update your php to accept 2 arguments - task id and completion state 0|1.

Comment: I think this is homework - it is identical to another questions I answered in much more detail than I would have, had it been homework

Comment: not sure what you mean with regards to homework. I had a look at your link but unfortunately I couldn't work out how to apply it in my own context it was a slightly different question. @user1514042 - thanks I took your advice and did it this way. There is probably a cleaner way but this made sense to me in my head- I have the Onclick pass 2 variables and the ajax /PHP  is essentially toggling between the 2 states. when it returns successfully, I used jquery to toggle between 2 different Onclick commands (with a variable of either 1 or 0).

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was to change up the php to accept 2 variables instead.It will toggle between the 2 states like so.

```
if ($_POST['completed'] == 0) { 
$query ="UPDATE PRJ_tasklist SET completed = 1 WHERE (taskno=".$_POST['id'].")";
$result = odbc_exec($con1, $query);

}
else if ($_POST['completed'] == 1) { 
    $query ="UPDATE PRJ_tasklist SET completed = 0 WHERE (taskno=".$_POST['id'].")";
    $result = odbc_exec($con1, $query);
}
```

the Ajax call now looks like this below. On a successfull return it alters the Onclick event being sent in the first place.

```
function checkboxChecked(id,completed)
{
var x = "task"+id;

$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "form_taskchecked.post.php",
  data: { action: "checked", 
          id: id, 
          completed:completed //1 or 0
          }
})

 .done(function( msg ) {
    //success
     $('#'+x).toggleClass("task-done");
     $('#badgeicon'+id).toggleClass("hidden");
        //toggle the onclick function


         if (completed==1){
            $('#checkbox'+id).attr('onclick','checkboxChecked('+id+',0)');
         } else if (completed==0){
            $('#checkbox'+id).attr('onclick','checkboxChecked('+id+',1)');
         } 

})

.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});


}
```